# Origin of suffix name

Tags: etymology, suffixes

I always have difficulty to remember the meaning of *suffix* (end part of a word), in the context of a word.
So, I looked for the origin of the word suffix, but to be honest I don't understand it:

[image: image description]

What is the relation with the latin words *sub* and *figere* and the end part of the word?

Comment: Subordinately fasten = attach to the sub/lower/backside (of a word).

Comment: This seems to be a question about a change in Latin not English, as the English word is almost unchanged from the Latin. But maybe you can explain what you are confused about: is it the change from a b to an f, or the change in meaning from *fix under* to *fix onto the end*?

Comment: @stuart is  the change in meaning from fix under to fix onto the end what confuses me.

Comment: Fix here doesn't mean correct a mistake. It means affix/stick/adhere/addend/glue/fasten.

Comment: I see. Affix or adhere to the backside of a word. It makes sense now. Thanks Yosef